# MongoDB output to browser

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello I'm learning mongoDB and trying to print out my database query results to the browser.

I have a program working where it writes the output JSON to the console using `console.log()`

Is there a way to use `res.send()` (using express) or `response.write()` and `response.send()` to simply output the raw JSON data that the database query gets?

In other words, How can I make my *database invokatation* return a string?

```
// Use connect method to connect to the server
var invokeDatabase = function() {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        console.log("Connected successfully to database server");

        findDocuments(db, function() {
            findDocumentsFiltered(db, function() {
                db.close();
            });
        });
    });
};

//routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Someone connected.")
    res.send("accessing database... " + invokeDatabase())
        //res.send('Welcome G')
})
```

Comment: JavaScript is working asynchronously. You need to use either callback function or pass res(response) object in side function like `invokeDatabase(res)` while you may response directly json from express by `res.json({titel:"Hello"})`.

Comment: If what you get back is an object and you need to provide a JSON object to the caller... convert it to JSON. `JSON.stringify(invokeDatabase())` is a generic way to do that; `res.json()` is more appropriate in this case.

Comment: http://justbuildsomething.com/node-js-best-practices/#1 is something worth reading for a beginner like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example may help you to understand

```
// Use connect method to connect to the server
var invokeDatabase = function(callback) {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        //assert.equal(null, err);
        if(err) {
            console.log("Unable to connect database");
            callback(err, null);
            return;
        }
        console.log("Connected successfully to database server");

        findDocuments(db, function() {
            findDocumentsFiltered(db, function(err, data) {
                callback(err, data);
                db.close();
            });
        });
    });
};

//Added for demo. Here users is collection 
var findDocumentsFiltered = function(db, callback) {
    db.collection('users').find({}).toArray(function(err, userList) {
        callback(err, userList);
    });
};

//routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Someone connected.")
    invokeDatabase(function(err, data) {
        if(err)
            res.status(500).json({error: err});
        else
            res.json(data);
    }))
        //res.send('Welcome G')
})
```

Comment: Thanks!  For whatever reason, the code within the anonymous function seems unreachable.  Does my invokeDatabase() method need callback at the bottom?

Comment: I have updated(to check successfully connected to database or not) above example. I would like to suggest you to first try to understand JavaScript like callback, event loop, etc. You should debug code either printing on console or assert.